# How to autoload a new WooCommerce datastore

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am replacing WC_CUSTOMER [database as per these instructions](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Data-Stores#creating-a-new-data-store). I'm struggling with the implementation at the moment though.

I am assuming that I need to create a custom plugin, which then swaps out the new class like so:

```
 function myplugin_set_wc_customer_data_store( $stores ) {
     $stores['customer'] = 'WC_Custom_Customer_Data_Store';
    return $stores;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'myplugin_set_wc_customer_data_store' );
```

Does the new class then exist in a src folder under the plugin's directory? Or does it need to go under the Woocommerce plugin's /includes/data-stores folder along with the other data stores?

In either or both cases, how is the class loaded?

So far, I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Invalid data store. in
>   /app/public/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php:92

Which is thrown from:

```
if ( ! class_exists( $store ) ) {
    throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid data store.', 'woocommerce' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

later at a point something like `new WC_Custom_Customer_Data_Store()` will be called. So you just need to have this class exist before it is called... example, you can include the php file that has this class inside your myplugin_set_wc_customer_data_store function... or add a hook action to init.

Comment: yes as soon as I required the class in my plugin, it was loaded and worked... I had expected some magic Wordpress autoloading... thanks !!